# How to change the ComboBox CHOOSE AN ITEM header after changing Language property

Tags: c#, combobox, localization, windows-phone-8.1

We are localizing our app and letting the user change the language dynamically while the app is running.

This is working well except for the ComboBox that lets them change the language.

Here is the XAML

```
    <ComboBox
    x:Name="label_Languages"
    x:Uid="label_Languages"
    Header="Preferred language"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Languages}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding LanguageSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"
    PickerFlyoutBase.Title="{Binding Title, Mode=OneWay}"
    SelectedValuePath="Name"
    SelectionChanged="label_Languages_SelectionChanged" >
  <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding NativeName}" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding EnglishName}" FontSize="14" Foreground="{ThemeResource TextBoxForegroundHeaderThemeBrush}" />
      </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Here is the C#

```
    private void label_Languages_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ComboBox languages = sender as ComboBox;

    SettingsViewModel vm = DataContext as SettingsViewModel;

    SettingsViewModel.Language language = label_Languages.SelectedItem as SettingsViewModel.Language;
    if (language != null)
    {
        string locale = language.Name;
        App.ChangeAppLanguage(locale);
        page_SettingsPage.Language = App.CultureInfo.Name;
        page_SettingsPage.FlowDirection = App.FlowDirection;

        // Modify the language of each page UI element and render it in the new language.

        label_Languages.Header = ResourceStrings.GetString("label_Languages.Header");

        // update a bunch of other items that all work perfectly!
    }
}
```

Here are the before and after screenshots showing how the CHOOSE AND ITEM doesn't change.
[image: Image when the locale is set to English]

[image: Image after the locale is set to Spanish]

How do I get the ComboBox to change it header? Thanks for your interest in this.

[UPDATE]

Based on @Dev Dua's suggestion, I added PickerFlyoutBase.Title="{Binding Title, Mode=OneWay}" to the ComboBox XAML and added the Title property to the ViewModel. After the language is changed in the ViewModel, RaisePropertyChanged for the Title property causes the Title property to be retrieved later. Presumably by the PickerFlyoutBase.Title binding. Unfortunately, even though the correct value is returned by the Title property, the ComboBox continues to show the English CHOOSE AN ITEM regardless.

Here is the ViewModel:

```
    public Language _LanguageSelected = null;
    public Language LanguageSelected
    {
        get { return _LanguageSelected; }
        set
        {
            _LanguageSelected = value;
            App.ChangeAppLanguage(_LanguageSelected.Name);
            RaisePropertyChanged("LanguageSelected");
            RaisePropertyChanged("Title");
        }
    }

    public string Title
    { get { return ResourceStrings.GetString("LanguageChooseAnItem.Title"); } }
```

Something appears broken in the ComboBox binding to the PickerFlyoutBase.Title property. Using a string constant in XAML works as expected.

Answer (score 5):

Use the PickerFlyoutBase.Title property! Bind it to whatever text is to be displayed.

```
 <ComboBox PlaceholderText="Something here" PickerFlyoutBase.Title="Edited">
            <ComboBoxItem Content="A"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="B"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="C"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="D"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="A"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="A"/>
 </ComboBox>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I updated the question to include my results. It almost works.

Comment: Does changing PickerFlyoutBase.Title="{Binding Title, Mode=OneWay}" to PickerFlyoutBase.Title="{Binding Title}" work? Because I have been able to bing the property this way.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I tried initially without specifying the Mode and then set the Mode to OneWay. Neither made a difference.